# Error with user input within calculator program

Tags: java

This is the code I used for the calculator program.

```
package javaapp;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApp {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner matt = new Scanner("System.in");
    double fnum; 
    double snum; 
    double answer;
    System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
    fnum = matt.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("Enter the Second number: ");
    snum = matt.nextDouble();
    answer = fnum + snum;
    System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at javaapp.JavaApp.main(JavaApp.java:10)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Where is line 10 in JavaApp.java?

Comment: @MonadNewb counting by hand and from the stack dump `fnum = matt.nextDouble();`

Answer (score 8):

Remove the quotes from the constructor of `Scanner` so that it's not attempting to read from a `String` source

```
Scanner matt = new Scanner(System.in);
```